# Hibernate is hanging on tx.commit

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hibernate class that requires 3 different sessions.  It currently uses 2 sessions and works perfectly.  The first session is used to read data from an external db.  The second session is used to save data to our internal db.  I'm adding a third session because, we need to keep track on the transaction regardless of whether or not the main transaction is successful (the XXXXUpdate object).  My problem is that the new session is hanging on tx.commit().

```
private synchronized void executeUpdate(Long manualUpdateTagIndex) throws Exception {
    LogPersistenceLoggingContext ctx = new LogPersistenceThreadContext().getLogPersistenceLoggingContext();

    DateTime minTriggerDate = parseDateTimeIfNotNull(minTriggerTime);
    DateTime maxTriggerDate = parseDateTimeIfNotNull(maxTriggerTime);
    Session webdataSession = null;
    Session XXXXUpdateSession = null;
    XXXXUpdate update = new XXXXUpdate();
    update.setExecutedAt(new DateTime());
    update.setStatus(WebdataUpdateStatus.Success);

    boolean commit = true;
    int tagCount = 0;
    List<Period> tagPeriods = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Long, DateTime> tagIndexes = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    try {

        XXXXUpdateSession = accountingService.openUnmanagedSession();
        XXXXUpdateSession.getTransaction().begin();
        XXXXUpdateSession.save(update);

        HierarchicalLogContext logCtx = new HierarchicalLogContext(String.valueOf(update.getId()));
        ctx.pushLoggingContext(logCtx);

        ctx.log(logger, Level.INFO, new XXXXLogMarker(), "Executing XXXX data transfer", new Object[]{});
        if (webdataSessionFactory == null){
            throw new Exception("Failed to obtain webdata session factory. See earlier log entries");
        }
        try {
            webdataSession = webdataSessionFactory.openSession();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            update.setStatus(WebdataUpdateStatus.ConnectionError);
            throw new Exception("Failed to obtain webdata connection", ex);
        }

        webdataSession.getTransaction().begin();

        if (manualUpdateTagIndex == null) { // automatic tags update

            XXXXUpdate lastUpdate = (XXXXUpdate) HibernateUtil.getCurrentSpringManagedSession()
                    .createCriteria(XXXXUpdate.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.isNotNull("latestTriggerTimestamp"))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("status", WebdataUpdateStatus.Success))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("manualUpdate", false))
                    .addOrder(Order.desc("latestTriggerTimestamp"))
                    .setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();

            DateTime lastUpdatedDate = Period.defaultEffectiveInstant;
            if (minTriggerDate != null) {
                lastUpdatedDate = minTriggerDate;
            }

            if (lastUpdate != null && lastUpdate.getLatestTriggerTimestamp() != null) {
                lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdate.getLatestTriggerTimestamp();
                ctx.log(logger, Level.INFO, new XXXXLogMarker(),
                        "Querying for tag event triggers newer than last update timestamp [" + lastUpdate.getLatestTriggerTimestamp() + "]", new Object[]{});
            } else {
                ctx.log(logger, Level.INFO, new XXXXLogMarker(), "Update has never run. Catching up with history", new Object[]{});
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<XXXXProcessedTagRequest> processedReqs = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSpringManagedSession()
                    .createCriteria(XXXXProcessedTagRequest.class).list();

            Query triggerQuery = webdataSession.createQuery(
                    "select trigger, "
                            + "trigger.TagIndex,"
                            + "req  "
                            + "from XXXXTagEventTrigger as trigger "
                            + "join trigger.req as req "
                            + "where trigger.EventType in (:eventTypes) "
                            + "and trigger.timestamp > :lastUpdateMinusDelta "
                            + (maxTriggerDate != null?"and trigger.timestamp < :maxDate ":"")
                            + "and req.CurrentState = :currentState "
                            + "order by trigger.timestamp,trigger.reqIndex");

            triggerQuery.setParameterList("eventTypes", new Object[]{5, 9});
            triggerQuery.setParameter("lastUpdateMinusDelta", lastUpdatedDate.minusHours(hoursToKeepProcessedReqs) );
            if (maxTriggerDate != null){
                triggerQuery.setParameter("maxDate", maxTriggerDate);   
            }
            triggerQuery.setParameter("currentState", 2);

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Object[]> allTriggers = triggerQuery.list();

            List<Object[]> unprocessedTriggers = removeProcessedTags(new ArrayList<Object[]>(allTriggers),processedReqs,ctx);

            for (Object[] row : unprocessedTriggers) {
                XXXXTagEventTrigger trigger = (XXXXTagEventTrigger) row[0];

                if (lastUpdatedDate == null || lastUpdatedDate.isBefore(trigger.getTimestamp().getMillis())) {
                    lastUpdatedDate = new DateTime(trigger.getTimestamp());
                }

                tagIndexes.put((Long) row[1], new DateTime(trigger.getTimestamp()));

                XXXXProcessedTagRequest processedReq = new XXXXProcessedTagRequest();
                processedReq.setReqIndex(((XXXXTagReq)row[2]).getReqIndex());
                processedReq.setTimestamp(trigger.getTimestamp());

                HibernateUtil.getCurrentSpringManagedSession().save(processedReq);
            }

            ctx.log(logger, Level.INFO, new XXXXLogMarker(),
                    "Found [" + unprocessedTriggers.size() + "] tag event triggers on [" + tagIndexes.size() + "] tags", new Object[]{});

            update.setLatestTriggerTimestamp(lastUpdatedDate);
        } else { // manual tag update
            ctx.log(logger, Level.INFO, new XXXXLogMarker(), "Executing manual update for tag index [" + manualUpdateTagIndex + "]", new Object[]{});

            DateTime now = new DateTime();
            tagIndexes.put(manualUpdateTagIndex, now);
            update.setLatestTriggerTimestamp(now);
            update.setManualUpdate(true);
        }

        if (tagIndexes.size() > 0) {

            int totalTagCount = tagIndexes.size();

            while (!tagIndexes.isEmpty()) {
                List<Long> batchIndexes = new ArrayList<>();
                Iterator<Map.Entry<Long, DateTime>> indexIt = tagIndexes.entrySet().iterator();

                while (indexIt.hasNext() && batchIndexes.size() < tagBatchSize) {
                    batchIndexes.add(indexIt.next().getKey());
                    indexIt.remove();
                }

                Map<Long, LocalTag> existingTags = new HashMap<>();
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<LocalTag> existingTagIds = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSpringManagedSession()
                        .createCriteria(LocalTag.class)
                        .add(Restrictions.in("tagIndex", batchIndexes))
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("currentVersion", true)).list();

                for (LocalTag lt : existingTagIds) {
                    existingTags.put(lt.getTagIndex(), lt);
                }

                ctx.log(logger, Level.INFO, new XXXXLogMarker(),
                        "Processing tag updates [" + tagCount + "-" + (tagCount + batchIndexes.size()) + "] of [" + totalTagCount + "]", new Object[]{});

                Criteria tagCriteria = webdataSession.createCriteria(XXXXTag.class);
                tagCriteria.add(Restrictions.in("TagIndex", batchIndexes));
                if (!includeTestTags) {
                    tagCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("TestTag", "0"));
                }
                tagCriteria.setFetchMode("XXXXTagMS", FetchMode.JOIN);
                tagCriteria.setFetchMode("XXXXTagPS", FetchMode.JOIN);
                tagCriteria.setFetchMode("XXXXTagCCList", FetchMode.JOIN);
                tagCriteria.setFetchMode("XXXXTagTA", FetchMode.JOIN);
                tagCriteria.setFetchMode("XXXXTagCP", FetchMode.JOIN);
                tagCriteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<XXXXTag> tags = tagCriteria.list();

                if (manualUpdateTagIndex != null && tags.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new ValidationException("No tag found for manual update tag index [" + manualUpdateTagIndex + "]");
                }

                for (XXXXTag tag : tags) {
                    update.getProcessedTags().add(updateTag(tag, tagIndexes.get(tag.getTagIndex()), existingTags));
                    tagCount++;
                    if (fireEventLastActions.contains(tag.getLastAction().trim())) {
                        tagPeriods.add(new Period(tag.getStartTime().getMillis(), tag.getStopTime().getMillis()));
                    }
                }

                HibernateUtil.getCurrentSpringManagedSession().flush();
                HibernateUtil.getCurrentSpringManagedSession().clear();

                webdataSession.clear();
            }
        } else {
            ctx.log(logger, Level.INFO, new XXXXLogMarker(), "No updates found", new Object[]{});
        }

        HibernateUtil.getCurrentSpringManagedSession()
        .createQuery("delete XXXXUpdate where executedAt < :purgeDate")
        .setParameter("purgeDate", new DateTime().minusDays(daysToKeepUpdateHistory))
        .executeUpdate();

        HibernateUtil.getCurrentSpringManagedSession()
        .createQuery("delete XXXXProcessedTagRequest where timestamp < :purgeDate")
        .setParameter("purgeDate", new DateTime().minusHours(hoursToKeepProcessedReqs))
        .executeUpdate();

        update.setStatus(WebdataUpdateStatus.Success);
        update.setTagCount(update.getProcessedTags().size());

        tagPeriods = Period.merge(tagPeriods);

        for (Period p : tagPeriods) {
            XXXXUpdatePeriod oup = new XXXXUpdatePeriod();
            oup.setXXXXUpdate(update);
            oup.setStartDate(p.getStart());
            oup.setEndDate(p.getEnd());
            update.getPeriods().add(oup);
        }

        HibernateUtil.getCurrentSpringManagedSession().flush();

        ctx.log(logger, Level.INFO, new XXXXLogMarker(), "XXXX data transfer complete. Transferred [" + tagCount + "] tag updates", new Object[]{});

        ctx.popLoggingContext(logCtx);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        HibernateUtil.getCurrentSpringManagedSession().clear();
        update.getProcessedTags().clear();
        update.setTagCount(0);
        update.setStatus(WebdataUpdateStatus.TransferError);
        commit = false;
        ctx.log(logger, Level.ERROR, new XXXXLogMarker(), "XXXX data transfer failed", new Object[]{}, ex);
        throw new Exception("XXXX data transfer failed", ex);
    } finally {
        try {

            XXXXUpdateSession.saveOrUpdate(update);
            XXXXUpdateSession.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            commit = false;
            ctx.log(logger, Level.ERROR, new XXXXLogMarker(), "Failed to save XXXX transfer update record", new Object[]{}, ex);
            throw new Exception("Failed to save XXXX transfer update record", ex);
        } finally {
            if (!commit) {
                webdataSession.getTransaction().rollback();
            } else {
                webdataSession.getTransaction().commit();
            }
            ResourceDisposer.dispose(webdataSession);
        }

    }

}
```

The new session is the XXXXUpdateSession.  The only new code is that which is related to this session.  It's some kind of timing issue because, when I use hibernate debug logging, the tx commits without issue.  It also commits when I attempt to debug the hibernate commit().  I do not have much experience with hibernate so, I'm probably missing something obvious.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have opened two transactions `webdataSession.getTransaction().begin();` which is causing the issue (20 & 37 lines in the above code).

You can open the second transaction after committing the first transaction.

Also, it is not a best practice to have long methods like which will be very hard to debug the issues and become the nightmare for maintenance/support of the project.

Comment: Thanks, I agree.  I didn't write it.  So, even if the two transactions are associated with different sessions, they cannot be open at the same time?

Comment: where did you flush XXXXUpdateSession ?

Comment: I committed at the end of the method in the nested finally.

 XXXXUpdateSession.saveOrUpdate(update);
 XXXXUpdateSession.getTransaction().commit();

I also tried flushing in the same place.  Same result.